# arduino uno if string cotains a word

Tags: string, arduino-uno

I very new to Arduino Uno and need some advice....so here we go.

I want to use my Arduino to:
1. read my serial data --received as plain text
2. look for a specific word within a line of data received
3. only transmit/print the complete string if it contains the specific "word"

I found this sketch and it works only if I'm looking for char

```
// Example 3 - Receive with start- and end-markers

const byte numChars = 32;
char receivedChars[numChars];

boolean newData = false;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("<Arduino is ready>");
}

void loop() {
    recvWithStartEndMarkers();
    showNewData();
}

void recvWithStartEndMarkers() {
    static boolean recvInProgress = false;
    static byte ndx = 0;
    char startMarker = '<';
    char endMarker = '>';
    char rc;

    while (Serial.available() > 0 && newData == false) {
        rc = Serial.read();

        if (recvInProgress == true) {
            if (rc != endMarker) {
                receivedChars[ndx] = rc;
                ndx++;
                if (ndx >= numChars) {
                    ndx = numChars - 1;
                }
            }
            else {
                receivedChars[ndx] = '\0'; // terminate the string
                recvInProgress = false;
                ndx = 0;
                newData = true;
            }
        }

        else if (rc == startMarker) {
            recvInProgress = true;
        }
    }
}

void showNewData() {
    if (newData == true) {
        Serial.print("This just in ... ");
        Serial.println(receivedChars);
        newData = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use String class methods.
you can get the Data using `Serial.readString()`
then use the String methods for looking for a specific word.
Here are some useful links

> https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString
>
> https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject